# How to bulk import users into userfrosting?

Tags: userfrosting

what is the best way to bulk import users into userfrosting?

I tried importing CSV into `uf_users` table with `flag_verified` and `flag_enabled` set to 1, with requisite fields (`id, user_name, display_name, password`)

While data shows up in admin interface, individual users are not able to login.

Comment: Are you certain that the password hashes for the users you are importing, are compatible with one of the [password hashing methods](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/7d780a2c0cd6bbf65204ef7f0c1f5b0032e34744/userfrosting/models/database/User.php#L498-L527) that UserFrosting supports?

Comment: Thanks alex for helping with this.

Comment: While this is may not be the best way to import, quest is on to find one ;-)

Comment: Hey, nice that you solve your issue! In [so] we encourage you to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as a good way to share your knowledge. So, instead of updating your question, do add an answer with the details. Cheers!

Comment: Sure @fedorqui! thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

** Solution provided by Alex (@alexw) **

Thanks to the create of UF Alex (@alexw), further to the discussion at https://chat.userfrosting.com/channel/support,  here is how import was solved - as suggested by Alex.

Add relevant rows to other related tables -

`uf_user_event` with fields `event = 'sign_up', occured_at = timestamp, description = 'user xyz successfully registered on...'`

`uf_group_user` with fields `user_id = with id of imported  user, group_id = 1` (that is default)

With this, the imported user is able to login!

Thanks Alex!